# Nested content element in TYPO3 for content box / card (Bootstrap) with FLUIDTEMPLATE

Tags: layout, typo3, typoscript, fluid, templating

I am currently changing the template system of the website of our football club. The website is currently build with TYPO3 6.2 with TemplaVoila as template engine and the CSS framework YAML. I want to change this now to native FLUIDTEMPLATE and the CSS framework Bootstrap (I do this with an own template extension).

I would like to do as much as possible with native TYPO3 methods and I want avoid external extensions as much as possible. We ran in a really messy situation with TemplaVoila and I want to avoid this in the future. After I changed the template system I also want to upgrade the TYPO3 to a newer version (7.6 or 8) but I would like to stay on 6.2 for the moment.

I have the following challenge for which I did not find a solution built-in TYPO3 methods:
Our website consists of two columns, one column for the main content and one column for a sidebar. In the sidebar, the content is displayed in boxes (using bootstrap cards, formerly panels).

A box consists of a headline and content. The content can be text, image or even a plugin (we use the extension *T3Sports* for our sports league management). Now I would like to create a (specially created) content element that represents a wrapper around the actual content. From this wrapper or content element the name for the headline of the box should be taken. Within this content element a content element can be created again, quite normally from the selection if you create a new content element in TYPO3.

With extensions such as *gridelements* or *fluidcontent* that would work, but I would like to know if this can also be done with built-in functionalities of TYPO3? So far I have found nothing, so I would be grateful for tips.

Thank you in advance for any tips,

Bastian

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own Fluid Styled Content - Content Elements (FSC-CEs).
[Here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/latest/AddingYourOwnContentElements/) you can find a tutorial.

But do you really need additional Content Elements (CEs)?
Two options come to mind:

1. change your CSS, so you can use std-CEs and if they occur in that special column they are styled different.
2. add the option for special layouts by evaluating the `layout` field to add the styling for specal boxes. (these boxes-styles can be used in every column)

In general: try to avoid container CEs just for a special styling. The handling in FE and BE is very complicated and confusing.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this yes, but then I have to upgrade first to TYPO3 7.6 to be able to use the extension Fluid Styled Content, correct?

Comment: One more thing: I think I need an additional content element for the box. The card component in Bootstrap 4 is build like this:
<div class="card">
  <h4 class="card-header">{Headline ContentElement_Parent}</h4>
  <div class="card-body">{ContentElement_Child}</div>
</div>

Comment: about your first question: Yes. Fluid Styled Content is available only for TYPO3 7.6.x or 8.7.x
about the second question: as far as I have understood, for what you are trying to do, I guess you should use EXT:gridelements.
You could even try to use EXT:Mask that uses plain TYPO3 functions (note: you'd need both Mask and EXT:mask_export) but I think that gridelements would be the better choice

Answer (score 0):

You could give the backport of fluid styled content a try: [content_rendering_core](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/content_rendering_core/): I used in in 6.2 to replace css styled content and it worked and then, after upgrading to 7 it was just a question of uninstalling content_rendering_core and installing fluid styled content (and include the static ts templates). 
I created a 'fluid styled' slider inspired from 'fluid_styled_slider' ([see git](https://github.com/ervaude/fluid_styled_slider)) under 6.2 and it ran perfectly after upgrades to 7.6 and, just recently, 8.7.10 without glitches, both in frontend and in backend).